# How to install virtualenv on windows path without permission denied error?

Tags: django, windows, virtualenv

I got a new computer and I am setting up my environments to run django. I'm installed python and virtualenv. In windows 10, I tried to run `virtualenv -p python .` in the directory C:\Users\user\Dev\folder, but I'm getting the following error:

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-18.1.dist-info\\entry_points.txt'
Consider using the`--user`option or check the permissions.`

How do I give myself permissions to create an environment here? I have all admin privileges.

I get this to work `python -m virtualenv .`, but I'm not sure why I can't get the other option to work. It's a suitable work around, but I've never had to do it this way before.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for this, follow these commands:

1. `python -m venv micah`
2. `micah\Scripts\activate`

Thats it, your virtual environment will be created also do all this with administrator CMD if you have permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the vitualenv's help, which you can check to type in your terminal:

```
virtualenv --help
```

You can read:

```
Usage: virtualenv [OPTIONS] DEST_DIR
```

Where `DEST_DIR` is the destination directory for your virtual env, just pick one that your user is able to edit/modify.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps help me out the same of your issue:

1. `cd` to your project folder
2. Type: `py -3 -m venv .venv` to create a virtual enviroment in the folder named "venv", you can change this by your own